# Theorem 2.3.6 from Leinster - why does this triangle commute?

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, adjoint-functors

I have a question about the last part of the proof of Theorem 2.3.6 from [Leinster](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf).

At the bottom of page 62, there is a diagram

[image]

Why does the yellow triangle commute?

Comment: Is this not (2.9) on the previous page?

Comment: @Tyrone As far as I understand, (2.9) is part of the proof of uniqueness, which assumes that the triangle identities are satisfied. But the last part of the proof is about existence, and he is trying to prove that the triangle identities are satisfied.

Comment: Isn't that coming directly from the uniqueness, see equation (2.9).

Comment: It seems to me that the text indicates $\varepsilon_{B}$ the unique map such that $G(\varepsilon_B)\eta_{GB}=1$. So apply that with $B=FA$.

Comment: Look the third line in the "Existence" part.

Comment: It's clear now.